# How to handle inputs with the same name in php to add/update them in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML input form which is have an unknown number of inputs in some stages, like when the user wants to enter more than one document he click on an add button so a new field appears to him (using JavaScript for sure).

I make the names of the inputs just the same but in an array like `<input name="something[]"/>` .. the problem is I don't know if what I am doing gonna work or not ..

HTML PART

```
    <input name="uat[]" type="date"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="uatedate[]" type="date"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="pgldate[]" type="date"/>
```

PHP PART

```
$j=0; 

while(j<100){
    $sql[j]= "insert into project scope values ('$uat[j]','$uatedate[j]' , '$pgldate[j]' ;)";

    $j++;
}
```

^^ Just before the "try"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PHP PART code with this code:

```
   $j = 0;
      while ($j < count($_POST['uat'])) {
         $sql[$j] = "insert into project scope values (" . $_POST['uat'][$j] . "," . $_POST['uatedate'][$j] . "," . $_POST['pgldate'][$j] . ")";
    $j++;
    }
```

Comment: I used " extract($_POST) ;" is this different ?